# Why is this grub-install not working

Tags: grub2, usb

I am trying to create a Windows bootable USB on Ubuntu.
However, while installing grub onto the USB with this command:
 `grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/xiej/JM1_CPRA_X64FRER_EN-US_DV9/boot" /dev/sdb`
, I get this error:

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/media/xiej/JM1_CPRA_X64FRER_EN-US_DV9/boot/grub'.
```

What is a "canonical path"? And why isn't the grub install working?

Answer (score 0):

While I admire you trying to do this through command line, and I wish I could, I can't. Instead I'd suggest:
Download grub installation online

```
  sudo apt-get install usb-creator-kde && sudo usb-creator-kde
```

Change Cd-Drive/Image to your grub installation, select your USB Drive below, select your other options, and hit **'Make Startup Disk'**

Now wait for it, as it may take up to 75 minutes depending on your computer, and once it is done, close The USB-Startup-Disk-Creator, and eject the USB. There ya go!

Comment: I am creating a windows usb, not an ubuntu usb

Comment: This works for creating windows as well, don't question it. Believe me.

Comment: When I try to add an .iso file, it doesn't show up...

Comment: Please explain, and add screenshots with a link, so I can understand what that means